# Why changes in css does not appear?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I am creating wordpress theme and it is all good.

Yesterday I completed the basic layout and left it to do coloring in next day. I tried some changes like changing text color, border color. Nothing appears in theme.

Then I copied it (whole theme folder) and changed the theme name (folder and css) all the style were the same, it happens.

Why the same css file shows nothing after making simple changes and the just a new name do all fine?

Comment: Sounds like a cache problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just answering if similar problem anybody faces.

Those days were my learning period of font-awesome so I did a silly mistake.

I just took one file and did not care about the related files mentioned inside CSS file. I should have updated the path or just taken all the folders.

Answer (score 4):

That's a classic caching problem.

**First solution**

You could clear your cache. If you don't know how to do this, just Google:

> How to clear cache Firefox|Chrome|IE

You have to do this after every change in your file.

**Second solution**

You could name your `CSS`-file with a timestamp. 
Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css?<?php echo(time()); ?>">
```

This would add on every reload the current timestamp. Right now, it would look like `stylesheet.css?1503983004`. One Second later it will be `stylesheet.css?1503983005`

This will prevent the caching of your browser.

The `?` is the indicator for [parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). This will not affect your `css` at all but your browser will think it's a different file.

**NOTE:** Remember to delete this if your theme is ready to go live.